# Mongoose select with populate not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am making a query in mogoose and if i add any parameter on a query select, the populate parameter goes missing for example i have the following schemas:

Department:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String,required: true,index: {unique: true}} ,
    text: String
})

module.exports=mongoose.model('Department',schema);
```

Employee:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId=mongoose.Schema.ObjectId;

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String,required: true} ,
    lastName: {type:String} ,
    birthday:Date,
    email:{type:String,required: true,index: {unique: true}},
    _department:{type:ObjectId,ref:'Department'},
    isUser:Boolean
},{ strict:false});    
module.exports=mongoose.model('Employee',schema);
```

if i make:

```
var query=mongoose.model('Employee').find();
query.select('email').populate('_department','name');
query.exec(function(err,data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

I get the following ouput

```
 [ { email: 'email@email.com.br', _id: 532e570864803bf505e51c81 } ]
```

**I would expect this:**

```
[ { _department: { _id: 532c77c3485925d806436981, name: 'bar' },
  email: 'email@email.com.br',
  _id: 532e570864803bf505e51c81,
  __v: 0 } ]
```

If i make the following:

```
var query=mongoose.model('Employee').find();
query.populate('_department','name');
query.exec(function(err,data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

I get this output

```
[ { _department: { _id: 532c77c3485925d806436981, name: 'bar' },
   name: 'mimimi',
  email: 'email@email.com.br',
  _id: 532e570864803bf505e51c81,
  __v: 0 } ]
```

What makes me wonder that the select is breaking the populate. 
My mongoose version is 3.8.8

Comment: What are you expecting `select` to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surely you just specify the [fields you want](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select). Currently you only have "email" so that is all you get:

```
var query=mongoose.model('Employee').find();
query.select('email _department').populate('_department','name');
query.exec(function(err,data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try my code:

```
const Employee= require('../models/employee');

Employee.find({}, 'email _department')
    .populate('_department', ['name'])
    .exec(function(err, list_employee) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        //Successful
        console.log(list_employee);
    });
```

Will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Work for me this in mongoose and here company_name field is getting populate via reference 
ModelName.find().populate('parent_id', 'company_name')
.select('username mobile firstname lastname company_name');