# Mongoose .populate doesn't work in conjunction with .select

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am trying to populate the user document with only the `name` and the populated `profile`. If I do the following:

```
User.find().populate("profile")
```

Output:

```
[  
   {  
      "securityQuestions":{  
         "isSetup":false
      },
      "videos":[  

      ],
      "events":[  

      ],
      "_id":"5c7965aeaf076938cc974610",
      "name":"Wade Aston",
      "email":"mrwadepro@gmail.com",
      "date":"2019-03-01T17:02:38.845Z",
      "__v":0,
      "profile":{  
         "_id":"5c7965afaf076938cc974612",
         "user":"5c7965aeaf076938cc974610",
         "profile_picture":"5c7965aeaf076938cc974611",
         "media_feed":[  

         ],
         "date":"2019-03-01T17:02:39.055Z",
         "__v":0
      },
      "profile_type":"DistrictAdminProfile",
   }
]
```

Which is nice, but I don't want all of the user fields, I just want the name and the populated profile. So if I do this:

```
User.find({}, "name profile").populate("profile")
```

Output:

```
[  
   {  
      "_id":"5c7965aeaf076938cc974610",
      "name":"Luke",
      "profile":"5c7965afaf076938cc974612"
   }
]
```

For some reason the select causes the populate not to work anymore. I tried implementing the same syntax from this post [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598099/mongoose-select-with-populate-not-working) but I get the same result. So odd to me! Thanks in advance =]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`select`**  `{name: true}` will only select name field

```
User.find().select({name: true}).populate("profile")
```

also if you want to select specific field from profile, you can select there as well

```
User.find().select(name: true).populate('profile', { __v: false })
```

this will not list **__V** field from profile.