# Mongoose nested select not working with populate - fields are still showing when they've been selected out

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a Post, User, Comment section with the following schemas:

```
postSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    post_title,
    post_description,
    post_timestamp,
    post_author:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "User"
    },
    post_likes:{
        type: [userSchema.schema]
    },
    post_comments:{
        type: [commentSchema.schema]
    }

)}
```

```
userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    username,
    email,
    password,
    date
})
```

```
commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    comment_description,
    comment_timestamp,
    comment_author:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "User",
        require:true,
    }
})
```

The format that I want my output is the following:

```
{
        "_id": "638bdf38b2ad86abe32455fd",
        "post_title": "This is a test post",
        "post_description": "abc...",
        "post_timestamp": "2022-12-03T23:41:04.292Z",
        "post_author": {
            "username": "test10"
        },
        "post_comments": [
            {
                "comment_description": "This is my first comment for this new post",
                "comment_timestamp": "2022-12-03T23:51:24.306Z",
                "comment_author": {
                    "username": "test10"
                }
            },
            {
                "comment_description": "This is my first comment for this new post",
                "comment_timestamp": "2022-12-04T10:06:22.091Z",
                "comment_author": {
                    "username": "test11"
                }
            }
      ]
}
```

i.e. for the `post_comments` I would like the `_id` and `__v` removed.

I'm receiving my post documents/objects from my server in the following format:

```
{
        "_id": "638bdf38b2ad86abe32455fd",
        "post_title": "This is a test post",
        "post_description": "abc...",
        "post_timestamp": "2022-12-03T23:41:04.292Z",
        "post_author": {
            "username": "test10"
        },
        "post_comments": [
            {
                "comment_description": "This is my first comment for this new post",
                "comment_timestamp": "2022-12-03T23:51:24.306Z",
                "comment_author": {
                    "username": "test10"
                },
                "_id": "638be126b9fe7d1b4823882c",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "comment_description": "This is my first comment for this new post",
                "comment_timestamp": "2022-12-04T10:06:22.091Z",
                "comment_author": {
                    "username": "test11"
                },
                "_id": "638c738ab63be98a89d2cb76",
                "__v": 0
            }
      ]
}
```

This is my code to get the data in my app.js route

```
const posts = await Post.find({}, {
            post_title: 1,
            post_description: 1,
            post_timestamp: 1
        })
        .populate({
            path: "post_author",
            model: "User",
            select: "-_id username",
        })
        .populate({
            path: "post_comments",
            model: "Comment",
            select: "-_id -__v comment_description comment_timestamp", // <-- This doesn't work
            populate: {
                path: "comment_author",
                model: "User",
                select: "-_id:0 username"
            }
        })
```

My select value doesn't make a difference for the post_comments bit. I could use it as is, but I'd like to understand why it's not working. I'm overlooking something but I'm not sure what it is.

I've tried writing the select in other ways, for example:

```
.populate({
            path: "post_comments",
            model: "Comment",
            _id: 0,
            __v: 0,
            // select: "-_id -__v comment_description comment_timestamp",
            populate: {
                path: "comment_author",
                model: "User",
                select: "-_id username"
            }
        })
```

and nothing I do seems to work

I've also tried the solution in this question: [Mongoose select with populate not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598099/mongoose-select-with-populate-not-working) but that hasn't worked either.

Doing:

```
.populate("post_comments", "comment_description")
```

Gives me the following output:

```
...
"post_comments": [
            {
                "comment_description": "This is my first comment for this new post",
                "comment_timestamp": "2022-12-03T23:51:24.306Z",
                "comment_author": "63697530dbf87061fa4c1665",
                "_id": "638be126b9fe7d1b4823882c",
                "__v": 0
            },

       ...
```